# How to read env variables using Node repl

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I read environment variables from the node console?
The steps I am doing are the following:

`node`

`> process.env.PORT`

`> undefined`

However, I have defined a PORT variable in a .env file. For context, I am working in an express project with the dotenv package included.

Comment: You need to require dotenv to load the file: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#usage

Comment: you need to do `require('dotenv').config()` to load it.

Answer (score 0):

When I import .env vars I put 'require("dotenv").config();' in the root index file(for node). Also note that any vars in the .env file are capitalized. So if our var was COOL_PORT=443 we would access it via process.env.COOL_PORT.